# UIPickerView returning "?" in columns

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7.1

I'm starting iOS development and I seem to have a bug!

Image: http://prntscr.com/4p1hfr

While using this code:

Recent.h:

```
 @interface RecentImages : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>

 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *imageURLs;

 @end
```

Recent.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 _imageURLs = @[@"test", @"test",
                  @"test", @"test", @"test"];
 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }
 #pragma mark -
 #pragma mark PickerView DataSource

 - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
 (UIPickerView *)pickerView
 {
     return 1;
 }

 - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
 numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
     return _imageURLs.count;
 }

 - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
         titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
        forComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
     return _imageURLs[row];
 }
 -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
  inComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
  NSLog(@"got it");

 }
```

It should be displaying "test" a few times right? Not "?". I'm very confused.

Comment: Are you certain the delegate methods are being called?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Place a breakpoint in numberOfRowsInComponent or titleForRow.  See if they are called.

Comment: Yes, they're reaching the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On which Xcode version are you facing this issue? As your code is working fine on ios 8 and Xcode 6. 
Still,you can try this code after populating your array->

self.pickerView.delegate = self;

self.pickerView.dataSource = self;

[self.pickerView reloadAllComponents];